# Type Mismatch, cannot convert from ObjA to ObjB (that extends the first one)

Tags: java

Let me explain:

```
package a.b.c.d;
public interface ObjA extends ObjFirst ...
```

then

```
package e.f.g.h;
public interface ObjB extends a.b.c.d.ObjA ...
```

I have a method from package a.b.c.d that return me an ObjA and when I try to implicitly cast it to ObjB it return the error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from a.b.c.d.ObjA to e.f.g.h.ObjB
```

where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called "downcast", and the compiler won't let you do it implicitly. That's because the compiler does not know whether an instance of `ObjA` is an instance of `ObjB` too.

Let's take this as example:

```
class Animal {
    //...
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    //...
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    //...
}
```

`Dog` [***is-an***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `Animal`, `Cat` [***is-an***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `Animal`.

So you will be able to do:

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
Animal animal = c;
```

But you won't be able to do:

```
Animal animal = new Animal();
Cat cat = animal;
```

In fact, try to think about it. If I tell you "I have an animal", how can you know for sure it *is a* cat?

If you want to downcast you have to do it explicitly:

```
/*
 * Here myAnimal is an Animal. In order to cast, 
 * I **must** be sure that myAnimal is a cat.
 */
Cat cat = (Cat) myAnimal;
```

In order to be really sure that `myAnimal` is a `Cat`:

```
if(myAnimal instanceof Cat) {
    Cat cat = (Cat) myAnimal;
    // do whatever you need to do with that cat object
}
```

Comment: that's clear, here I do not have a Dog and a Cat, but a Dog(ObjA) and a Dog(ObjB) with an additional method "jump" in it.

Comment: @MiPnamic Can you clarify? Based on the question it seems that you are trying to do `instanceOfObjB = instanceOfObjA`. You can't, you **must** do `instanceOfObjB = (ObjB) instanceOfObjA`, because `ObjB` is a subclass/subinterface of `ObjA`

Comment: I got it now, sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

Since `ObjB` is a sub-interface of `ObjA`, you can't pass `ObjA` instances to methods/variables that expect `ObjB` instances without an explicit cast, since not all `ObjA` instances are `ObjB` instances (you might have an `ObjC` interface that extends `ObjA` and does not implement `ObjB`).

You should check the type of the variable (using `var instanceof ObjB`) and then explicitly cast is to `ObjB` (using `(ObjB) var`).

Answer (score 1):

ObjB know about ObjA and ObjFirst

ObjA know about ObjFirst

But here we are trying to cast ObjA to ObjB where it was not aware of.
we can check this simply by using "instanceof" operator

ObjB instanceof ObjA is true

ObjA instanceof ObjB returns false

Answer (score 0):

You need to actively cast it, as down-casting is not supported. By trying to down-cast, you are implicitly expecting the system to try and find the interface in something which could be best described as an inheritance-tree. Problem is, that if down-casting would be supported, then whenever you are using an object of some arbitrary type, the system should always try to find the sub-class/sub-interface matching it. It can be supported or not. In our case it is not supported and I believe that is a very good thing. What if no such subclass, subinterface exists? It would be a runtime-exception, possibly when the code is already released.